# How to split a complex string into its components so inorder to form groups

Tags: r, database, string, split, dataframe

How to split a string SU000062941195709TMAX which contains all the information. In a columns of  SU000062941 1957 09 TMAX in a data.frame so that I can use tapply on these groups?

Comment: Are the parts of the string always the same length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string is of fixed width, you can use `read.fwf`

```
 read.fwf(file="filefw.txt", widths=c(11,4,2,4))
#          V1   V2 V3   V4
#1 SU000062941 1957  9 TMAX
```